# Alternative for Thunderbird for Linux

Tags: linux, email-client

I'm looking for an alternative for Thunderbird. I use Linux. An alternative should meet three requirements:

- support multiple email accounts
- be able to reside in tray, and does not depend on helpers like Alltray¹ for this
- be able to display information about new mail

---

¹ <sub>AllTray is an application which docks other application software into the system tray</sub>

Comment: Still a bit vague. Aren't all those 3 requirements met by Thunderbird itself? So what don't you like about Thunderbird? Would Gnome Evolution fit (it's in the standard repos)? What is alltray (and didn't you rather mean your wanted mail client should not *need* alltray)?

Comment: I don't like Thunderbird. "AllTray is an application which docks other application software into the system tray". I want a program that doesn't need `alltray`. Please feel free to edit my question if you find it vague.

Comment: If I could do that, I wouldn't write it's vague. I cannot tell what you dislike with Thunderbird – and unless you tell us, you risk the recommendations including those unwanted parts as well :) Currently, apart from the Alltray part, your requirements would be met by any GUI mail client (uh, just checked: strike Evolution, it would need Alltray as well).

Answer (score 1):

[Mailspring](https://getmailspring.com) is a fine solution too.

Comment: Why? [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: +1, ***BUT***, all of your answer are belong to us :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/) for years.

Comment: Have a look at the official [Claws screenshots](http://www.claws-mail.org/screenshots.php?section=general) webpage.